# how to connect coordinator running over zigbee with end device (Xbee, S1)

Tags: zigbee

How can i connect Xbee s1(having zigbee) as end device to a board running as zigbee co-ordinator?
As i am unable to connect one Xbee device (s1) to coordinator (zigbee) running over board.

Answer (score 0):

I think XBee S1 does not have ZigBee protocol (as far as I know). XBee S1 uses 802.15.4 protocol to communicate with other device (module) and can not talk to other ZigBee device(s). But, anyway, to connect to other XBee S1 and doing simple sending and receiving data, you can configure them with [XCTU](http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=2125).

Answer (score 0):

Series 1 xbee's can't load the Zigbee firmware as mentioned. You need to go into XCTU and load either 802.15.4 or Digimesh. I recommend Digimesh. Then just set them to broadcast and it should work. Otherwise for unicast communication you have to set the destination address of the transmitting xbee to the serial number of the receiving xbee (which is on the back of the xbee or you can read it from XCTU after pressing the 'read' button while having the xbee attached.